# Angular 2: transfer data from parent to child

Tags: angular, components, communication, interaction

I have a component with a router outlet. This component has a select element which I feed with some categories on ngOnInit through a service. There are 3 child routes and one of them navigates to a component that also wants to make use of those categories.

My routes look like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: 'marketplace',
  component: MarketplaceComponent,
  resolve: { categories: CategoriesResolveService },
  canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard],
  children: [      
    { path: 'modules', component: ModulesComponent, resolve: { categories: CategoriesResolveService } }      
  ]
}];
```

This is making 2 http calls to get the categories. How can I transfer this data to the child component? I want to avoid doing another http call. Is it possible to share this data between parent and child?

Comment: Are you try with viewChild() ?

Comment: have no idea what viewChild is, will have a look, thanks

Comment: ViewChild works by having the child component declared in the parent's template? if so then I think it will not work in this scenario, i only have the router outlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class parentComponent  {

   @ViewChild(ChildOneComponent)
   private childOneComponent: ChildOneComponent;

   @ViewChild(ChildTwoComponent)
   private childTwoComponent: ChildTwoComponent;

   let date = this.childOneComponent.method1;

}
```

this method1() is define in your child component for get method.you must import child components in your parent component.

```
ChildOneComponent {
  get method1() {
     return this.value//return which value you pass.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

[Pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)